# How do you use a png string in the PHP function imagecreatefromstring?

Tags: php, string, png

I have a file call it $png_file which is a string taken from the database.
I want to be able to use it in the following way:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($png_file);
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
```

so that I can get the height and width of the png file that is saved in the database as a string.

However, everytime i try to do this I get the following errors:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-png: fatal libpng error: Read Error: truncated data in  on line 39
Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-png error: setjmp returns error condition in  on line 39
Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Passed data is not in 'PNG' format in  on line 39
Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Couldn't create GD Image Stream out of Data in  on line 39
Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in  on line 40
Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in  on line 41
```

How can I fix this? and note that the png file is a string, and I can't get it as a url

Comment: It's not possible to help you when you don't show how you get your image data at all.  You haven't shown any relevant code.  Either your image is corrupt, or you are fetching it in an odd way.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. You will get an idea about "imagecreatefromstring" function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: need more explanation when u add an answer

Answer (score 0):

May be late but you might try:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($png_file));
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
```

Notice the: `file_get_contents` part.

Hope it helps